# Display different view controllers based on role-Firebase, Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I'm building a pretty simple app that sends reports from a user to an admin. So far i have the entire front end done. I have the menu working, and the report sequence is seemless. Now its time for me to take on the back end. I am a new Swift developer, completely self taught(like you should be :) ) and i'm stumped on a few things. I just need some guidance, i've used stack overflow in the back for advice by just reading but have never asked a question. So! my question to you, the godly stack community, is!:

I have two roles for users..

1. A normal User
2. An admin

I want to be able to, based on their role in firebase, when they login redirect them to their respective view controller. Now! i asked a friend of mine who told me they can all be done in the same app, i dont need to make a different app for the admins. I'm guessing this is true because i trust his judgement. I was thinking of doing if checks ie

```html
//If role is = to admin
self.performSegue(admin VC)

//else
self.performSegue(homeScreen)
```

I am having issues 1. assigning the role and 2. accessing it from firebase!

Any insight/tips is much appreciated!

Thank you stack overflow gods

Comment: Well you can read here all about it: https://firebase.google.com/docs/ and when you have a specific question you can ask it again, since your question is to broad

Answer (score 1):

This will be a two step process

Step one is to authenticate the user and retrieve their user uid

```
Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: "dude@thing.com", password: "password", 
  completion: { (auth, error) in

    if error != nil {
        let err = error?.localizedDescription
        print(err!)
    } else {
        print("succesfully authd")
        let uid = auth!.uid

        assignUserRole(uid)     
    }
})
```

Assuming you have a standard users node which contains additional user data

```
users
  uid_0
   fav_food: "pizza"
   user_role: "admin"
  uid_1
   fav_food: "tacos"
   user_role: "normal_user"
```

Step 2: the assignUserRole function will then be called to get the user information and set up the UI

```
function assignUserRole(theUid: String) {

   let thisUserRef = appRef.child("users").child(theUid)
   thisUserRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
       let userDict = snapshot.value as! [String: Any]
       let favFood = userDict["fav_food"] as! String
       let userRole = userDict["user_role"] as! String
       print("  \(favFood)  \(userRole")

      if userRole == "admin" {
        //display admin viewController
      } else {
        //display normal user viewController
     }
   })
}
```

Comment: Nice work! but I wonder if you could tell me the difference between your method and custom claims( JWTs) in the situation like this

Comment: @akaak I don't understand your question. What is *custom claims(JWTs)*? Happy to help just need to know in what context so I can draw a comparison.

Comment: This is the additional information you can store besides email and password when you sign up. https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims?hl=en. Maybe storing {admin: true} or {admin: false} to each user in custom claims is another solution to this.

Comment: @akaak That's the documentation for the Admin SDK which is different than the Firebase Realtime Database SDK and the Authentication API. The admin SDK is Java/Web (not swift) and is aimed at developers who want to have a finer level of control outside their app or want to integrate an external user system or leverage your own server.

Comment: thanks your time answering. I just found this article written by Firebase developer saying this can be done for any client sides, Swift, Android, and Web. https://medium.com/google-developers/controlling-data-access-using-firebase-auth-custom-claims-88b3c2c9352a

Comment: @akaak Interesting read! and good to know we can access with Swift. Going back to your original question, the article states *Perhaps you want to add a home address, additional photo URLs, or a profile description, for example. But this is not what custom claims are designed for. Data like addresses should be stored in a database, since it’s not related to authentication.*. So it appears you could store that type of data, but they are recommending not to. I'm not sure where the distinction between an admin user and standard user would be stored in that case. Going to have a read up a bit more.

Answer (score -1):

It's hard to give a precise answer since your question is rather broad but something along these lines should accomplish what you're going for. Just be sure to switch out the placeholders with the correct information:

```
//Fetch user role from Firebase DB
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("PATH_TO_YOUR_USER_OBJECT").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

    //Obtain value of user role
    let snapValue = snapshot.value as! [String:AnyObject]
    let userRole = snapValue["KEY_OF_USER_ROLE"] as! String

    //Set default vc in case of error
     var viewControllerID = "DEFAULT_VC_ID"

    //Set vc based on user role
    if userRole == "admin" {
        viewControllerID = "ADMIN_VC_ID"
    } else {
        viewControllerID = "USER_VC_ID"
    }

    //Instantiate correct vc and make it the root vc
    self.storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "YOUR_STORYBOARD_NAME", bundle: Bundle.main)
    self.window?.rootViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: viewControllerID)
})
```

Comment: No. You can't 'fetch' data from Firebase like that. The reference.value does not contain any paths to custom user data, and it's not key:value coding compliant either.